# How to modify existing Excel workbook with Java

Tags: java, excel

My goal is to open an existing Excel file (xlsx)

1. add and name new sheets
2. add rows with data (multiple columns)
3. give column headings

This seems to be a really adventure. I now opened 30 tabs in my browser to solve one problem followed by another.

I added the following jars to my java project

- commons-collections4-4.1.jar
- commons-compress-1.19.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar
- poi-4.0.1.jar
- poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.0.1.jar
- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

I imported the poi-4.1.0 to my project. Now I have tons of files in my project but still got errors.

The last one I cannot resolve is:

> The type org.etsi.uri.x01903.v13.SignaturePolicyIdType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files XAdESSignatureFacet.java

`Resource: XAdESSignatureFacet.java`

Can anyone give an working java example. Can´t believe that this has to be so complicated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by recreate the properties of my java project.

Java Build Path - Libraries:

- commons-codec-1.12.jar
- commons-collections4-4.3.jar
- commons-compress-1.19.jar
- commons-io-1.3.jar
- commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
- curvesapi-1.06.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- poi-4.1.0.jar
- poi-examples-4.1.0.jar
- poi-ooxml-4.1.0.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.0.jar
- poi-scratchpad-4.1.0.jar
- xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar

JRE System Library [jre1.8.0_221]

Java Code:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook;
workbook = getWorkBook("path to existing workbook", new XSSFWorkbook());
XSSFSheet spreadsheet;
spreadsheet = workbook.cloneSheet("the index number of the sheet to be cloned", "the name of the sheet you want to create");

FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream("excel file directory path");
        try {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can implement all the necessary stuff to fit your needs. Exceptions etc. 
I filled rows and columns depending on data provided in CSV files with plausibility
checks and validations.

Java Code Example:

```
Row row; 
Cell cell;
row = spreadsheet.createRow("row index");
cell = row.createCell("column index");
cell.setCellValue("String");
```

with this implementation I meet my above mentioned goals except goal 3 which has become superfluous because the sheet to be cloned already inherit the column headings.

thanks for your replies

Answer (score -2):

There is a comprehensive guide on that here: [link](https://www.java67.com/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html?m=1)

Comment: Link only answers should be avoided, links can be changed or their content removed.